# Implement a 5-minute edit window for annotations in main and chat

Tags: feature-request, chat, moderator-tools

As of now, moderator annotations in main and chat (on user profiles) have no edit window. Sometimes I miss certain details or make some spelling or grammar errors at the first go. It would nice if a 5 minute (or maybe longer) edit window could be implemented.

Is there any specific reason why this hasn't been implemented yet?

Comment: I sometimes forget that markdown is limited in annotations and end up with something hard-to-read that I'd like to fix.